# Process in ServiceMix with Apache ODE JBI component

Tags: apache-servicemix, apache-ode

I installed Servicemix with the Apache ODE JBI component, and then I deployed the example HelloWorld2, which has  two service units:  Ode bpel engine (for the process) and http (for the external end point). Externally  I tested with soapUI and works fine.

Then I modified the HelloWorld2 service assembly to works only with the service unit of Ode, and  I've "accesed" to the proccess using PMAPI, and I've obtained information about the process (TProcessInfo), fine too.

I have not clear if there is a chance to interact/initiate a process of externally without any external endpoint exposed from the ESB.

Please help, and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Do I understand that correctly that you want to instantiate a process instance and access it remotely without using an external endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I want to instantiate a process instance and access it remotely without using an external endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not how JBI or ServiceMix works. SMX is in charge of exchanging messages between service endpoints exposed by service engines or binding components. The former can host setvice units that contain and provide an implementation of a certain functionality, such as a BPEL process or a JAXWS service. The latter can externalize internal endpoints, either to invoke remote services or to make the implementation accessible via a certain transport protocol. Thus,  without defining a service unit for a binding component that exposes the internal process endpoint via some transport, it is not possible to access the process from the outside world. Only other service engines or binding components may directly access internal endpoints